# What is the problem in this code while JSON parsing?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley, android-broadcast

The program get data from web server and put the data in an `arrayList`. If the size of the `arrayList` is larger than 1 , It work successfully. But if it's smaller, that must show the error screen that I set.

My question is when it has two different tabItem and get two different array, If one of them size are not bigger than 1. It show error message in same page. And also show data in the page. How can I make show this screen when which doesn't have data?
[image: There is data but show error page also.]
[image: This is normal there is no data and show error page.]

This is the class that which get data from web server.
Voyage.java

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
if (object.getString(MyConstants.SERVICE_STATUS).equals(MyConstants.SERVICE_RESPONSE_STATUS_NOTAVAILABLE)) {
    sendVoyagesErrorBroadcast(owner, MyConstants.ERROR_NOTAVAILABLE);
} else if (object.getString(MyConstants.SERVICE_STATUS).equals(MyConstants.SERVICE_RESPONSE_STATUS_SUCCESS)) {
    JSONArray result = object.getJSONArray(MyConstants.SERVICE_RESULT);
    if (result.length() > 0) {
        JSONArray resultGoing = result.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("going");
        sendVoyagesArrayBroadcast(owner + MyConstants.DIRECTION_GOING, resultGoing);
    } else {
        sendVoyagesErrorBroadcast(owner, MyConstants.ERROR_NO_VOYAGE);
    }
    if (has_return) {
        if (result.length() >1) {
            JSONArray resultReturn = result.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("round");
            sendVoyagesArrayBroadcast(owner + MyConstants.DIRECTION_RETURN, resultReturn);
        } else {
            sendVoyagesErrorBroadcast(owner, MyConstants.ERROR_NO_VOYAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class that which parse JSON array and check size of array.
MyBaseVoyagementFragment.java

```
public ParseIntentDataAndLoadVoyagesAdapter(Intent intent) {
    this.intent = intent;
}

@Override       
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    if (isCancelled()) return "";
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(intent.getStringExtra("data"));
        voyageList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            voyageList.add(Voyage.setJsonToClass(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i), direction, owner));
        }

        if (voyageList.size() < 1) {
            setErrorView(MyConstants.ERROR_NO_VOYAGE);
        }
```

These are the brodcast function to Send array and send error.

```
// sonuç aldım diye sinyal gönderiyorum.
private void sendVoyagesArrayBroadcast(String target, JSONArray resultArray) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(BROADCAST_TAG + target);
    intent.putExtra("data", resultArray.toString());
    /*if(!target.contains("bus2")){
        Log.e("sendSuccessBroadcast",target);
        intent.putExtra("data", resultArray.toString());
    }*/

    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private void sendVoyagesErrorBroadcast(String target, int errorCode) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(BROADCAST_TAG + target + "Error");
    intent.putExtra("data", errorCode);
    Log.e("sendErrorBroadcast", target);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Edit: Added setErorView function.

```
   void setErrorView(int errorType) {
    if (errorType == MyConstants.ERROR_NOTAVAILABLE && owner == "ship") {
        if (SeawayReturnFragment.tabLayout != null)
            SeawayReturnFragment.tabLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        SeawayDepartureFragment.tabLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    errorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    TextView tvDesc = errorView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Desc);
    tvDesc.setText(getErrorDesc(errorType));
}
```

And the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingLeft="16dp"
   android:paddingRight="16dp"
   android:paddingTop="8dp">

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView25"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img_Type"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Bir şeyler ters gitti"
    android:textColor="@color/md_grey_500"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_Type"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cd_Error"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_sadf" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_Desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView25"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
 android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    android:textColor="@color/md_grey_400"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: can you share your xml layout files? and where are you setting the error screen? and share the code in `setErrorView` method?

Comment: Sorry, I replied you late. I editted them in question now.

Comment: i guess its some sort of background image that get hide behind data when data length is greater then one

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammilSharif It's not about image I think. The broadcast and if clause that I use while parsing data in Voyage.java.

Comment: you want to show those error that you are sending in broadcast into your respective fragments

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammilSharif I solved problem. The problem reason happened because "round" were not sending from web service. So it send empty now and problem solved. Should I delete this question?

Comment: may be answer your own question with the solution will be good

Answer (score 1):

I solved problem. The problem doesn't happen by my codes. It happen because of by web server. The program get "going" and "round" array from web server. Server doesn't send "round" array so It make this problem in my program. Now they fix and it send empty array as "round". So, my problem is solved.